# How to combine 2 arrays into 1 array

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays like that:

```
array1
      (
        [0] => Array
                   (
                     [id] => 133
                   )

        [1] => Array
                   (
                     [id] => 134
                   )

      )

array2
      (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2

      )
```

My problem is: how can I combine two arrays into one array like:

```
array3
      (
        [133] => 1
        [134] => 2

      )
```

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  $array3[$value['id']] = $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3 = array_combine(array_map('current', $array1), $array2);
```

Comment: What is "current" in the map?

Comment: It takes the [current](http://php.net/current) (first) element from the child array, in essence flattening the array.

Comment: Nice tip deceze. This is a much tidier solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this:

```
<?php
    $arrayOne = array(
        array("id" => 133),
        array("id" => 134)
    );
    $arrayTwo = array(1,2);
    $arrayThree = array();
    foreach($arrayOne as $index => $value){
        $arrayThree[$value['id']] = $arrayTwo[$index];
    }
```

if you do a

```
print_r($arrayThree);
```

now you will get your third array:

```
Array
(
    [133] => 1
    [134] => 2
)
```